# Media queries in iOS 7 not working

Tags: ios, media, ios7

I'm using a couple of media queries that target iPad and iPhone in landscape as well as portrait orientation, but as of iOS 7 they don't work anymore. They worked perfectly in iOS 6, though. Has anyone had a similar experience?

Here's part of the code I'm using:

```
<style type="text/css">
/* iPad (landscape) */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
.header {
font-family: courier new, monospace;
color: #999999;
font-size: 14pt;
line-height: 104%;
width: 37.5em; }
.action {  
font-family: courier new, monospace;
color: #999999;
font-size: 14pt;
line-height: 104%;
width: 37.5em; }
.character {  
font-family: courier new, monospace;  
color: #999999;
font-size: 14pt;
line-height: 104%;
padding-left: 12.25em;
width: 21em; }
.dialogue {
font-family: courier new, monospace;  
color: #999999;
font-size: 14pt;
line-height: 104%;
padding-left: 6.15em;
width: 22em; }
.info {  
display: none; }}
/* iPad (portrait) */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
.header {
font-family: courier new, monospace;
color: #999999;
font-size: 12pt;
line-height: 104%;
width: 37.15em; }
.action {  
font-family: courier new, monospace;
color: #999999;
font-size: 12pt;
line-height: 104%;
width: 37.15em; }
.character {  
font-family: courier new, monospace;  
color: #999999;
font-size: 12pt;
line-height: 104%;
padding-left: 12em;
width: 21em; }
.dialogue {
font-family: courier new, monospace;  
color: #999999;
font-size: 12pt;
line-height: 104%;
padding-left: 6em;
width: 22em; }
.info {  
display: none; }}
</style>
```

Comment: Here's the website I'm experiencing problems with: http://story-architect.com/?p=1614

Comment: same here, still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you paste the media query you are trying to use to achieve the iPad only selection. I was having the same problem but noticed I had added text by accident that was causing one of my queries to not close correctly. Make sure all of your media queries and properties have been closed prior to your iPad query. Below is an example of the two queries I use to determine iPad and orientation:

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {}

or

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape){}

I have used these on multiple responsive designs I have created and they work correctly on both iOS6 and iOS7. Again, just checkout your code. May be your overlooking something quite simple. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts on this. You can go to http://story-architect.com/?p=1614 and scroll down and download the CSS I'm using.

Comment: The problems are a result of the iPhone 5 media query. Working on a fix now.

Comment: Try your portrait query on a page with an input field that is focused so the keyboard is displayed on an iPad running iOS7. I find that as soon as the keyboard appears the orientation: portrait is no longer true.

Comment: I just tested it on my iPad 2 running iOS7 and didn't notice the problem. What's the URL of the site you're testing this on?

Answer (score 6):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

Make sure your html code includes this line.

Answer (score 0):

i am experiencing the same problem. my meta tags as requested.

/* phone-portrait */
@import url("phone-portrait.css")   only screen
                                    and (min-width:320px )
                                    and (max-width: 568px )
                                    and ( orientation: portrait );

/* phone4 -landscape*/ 
@import url('phone-landscapeFour.css')  only screen
                                        and (min-width:321px ) 
                                        and (max-width: 480px)
                                        and (orientation: landscape );

/* phone5 -landscape*/ 
@import url('phone-landscapeFive.css')  only screen
                                        and (min-width:481px ) 
                                        and (max-width: 568px)
                                        and (orientation: landscape );

/* ---------- Tablets ---------- */
@import url("tablet.css")   only screen
                            and (min-width: 569px )
                            and (max-width: 1024px)
                            and (orientation: portrait);

@import url('tablet-landscape.css') only screen
                                    and (min-width: 569px)
                                    and (max-width: 1024px)
                                    and (orientation: landscape);

Answer (score 0):

Use aspect-ratio and device-aspect-ratio instead. Bulletproof iOS media queries...

```
/* iPad: portrait */
@media screen and (aspect-ratio: 768/716) and (device-aspect-ratio: 768/1024), screen and (aspect-ratio: 768/1024) and (device-aspect-ratio: 768/1024) {
    /* styles here */
}

/* iPad: landscape */
@media screen and (aspect-ratio: 1024/372) and (device-aspect-ratio: 768/1024), screen and (aspect-ratio: 1024/768) and (device-aspect-ratio: 768/1024) {
    /* styles here */
}

/* iPhone 3.5" screen: portrait */
@media screen and (aspect-ratio: 320/220) and (device-aspect-ratio: 320/480), screen and (aspect-ratio: 320/480) and (device-aspect-ratio: 320/480) {
    /* styles here */
}

/* iPhone 3.5" screen: landscape */
@media screen and (aspect-ratio: 480/114) and (device-aspect-ratio: 320/480), screen and (aspect-ratio: 480/320) and (device-aspect-ratio: 320/480) {
    /* styles here */
}

/* iPhone 4" screen: portrait */
@media screen and (aspect-ratio: 320/308) and (device-aspect-ratio: 320/568), screen and (aspect-ratio: 320/568) and (device-aspect-ratio: 320/568) {
    /* styles here */
}

/* iPhone 4" screen: landscape */
@media screen and (aspect-ratio: 568/114) and (device-aspect-ratio: 320/568), screen and (aspect-ratio: 568/320) and (device-aspect-ratio: 320/568) {
    /* styles here */
}
```

Comment: A warning about this: This will prevent responsiveness from working on anything other than what's listed above (e.g. Android devices, a small browser window).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in the meta tag viewport with the property:  height=device-height
Don't know why did I specified it. Maybe I broke something else in my project..

Removing it, orientation started working again on ios.