# Media query for iphone7

Tags: html, css

I'm using a couple of media queries that target iPad and iPhone in landscape as well as portrait orientation, but as of iOS 7 they don't work anymore. They worked perfectly in iOS 6, though. Has anyone had any similar experiences?

Comment: Post the media queries you're using, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your media queries and properties have been closed prior to your iPad query. Below is an example of the two queries I use to determine iPad and orientation:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {}
```

or

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
//iPhone 7 in portrait & landscape

@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 375px)
and (max-device-width : 667px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

//iPhone 7 in landscape
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 375px)
and (max-device-width : 667px)
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

//iPhone 7 in portrait
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 375px)
and (max-device-width : 667px)
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

And for the iPhone 7 Plus:

```
//iPhone 7 Plus in portrait & landscape
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 414px)
and (max-device-width : 736px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

//iPhone 7 Plus in landscape
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 414px)
and (max-device-width : 736px)
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

//iPhone 7 Plus in portrait
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 414px)
and (max-device-width : 736px)
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

Comment: I used that above media query but any changes in mobile device. what will do? "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952156/media-queries-in-ios-7-not-working". I read that forum is it true?